# How do I add a PDF to an Excel document using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I use the EPPlus library in C#.

I have a Worksheet and can add pictures to it.

```
Worksheet sheet;
...
sheet.Sheet.Drawings.AddPicture(name, bitmap);
```

I would also like to add a PDF. I could supply the PDF as a Stream or a BinaryData or even a filename with path, but I find no support in the Worksheet class.

Should I use another class?

Should I use another field in Worksheet?

The Wiki says "What is not supported ... Embedded Objects". It might be outdated or not updated.

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Would it make sense to render the PDF as an image in c#, and just insert it like that? I mean, most PDF's are just images with some HTML wrapped up into them anyways.

Comment: Microsoft dropped a lot of supported for embedded objects about 7 years ago. So it wouldn't make sense for EPPlus to support it, as no modern version of Office would be allowed to open it. I'd suggest the same as Kevin B Burns.

Comment: I can put a PDF into an Excel file using the latest version of Excel.